# Mongodb one to many associations embedded cannot read property push of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm starting with associations in Mongodb and I'm running into that error when I try to push the post contents to one user using the embedded process:

Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

This is my code:

```html
var mongoose= require("mongoose");



mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/associations");

// User
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String,
 email: String
});

var User= mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


// POst
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,
 content: String
 
});

var Post= mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);


var newUser= new User({
 name: "Roy",
 email: "c@gmail.com",
 posts: [postSchema]
});

newUser.posts.push({
 title: "Myself",
 content: "I'm happy"
});

newUser.save(function(err,user){
 if (err) {
  console.log(err);
 }else{
  console.log(user);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue about the order, the Post Schema and model should go before the user Schema and model. This is the proper way to store things:

```html
var mongoose= require("mongoose");



mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/associations");




// POst
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,
 content: String
 
});

var Post= mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);


// User
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String,
 email: String,
 posts: [postSchema]
});

var User= mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

var newUser= new User({
 name: "Roy",
 email: "c@gmail.com"
});

newUser.posts.push({
 title: "Myself",
 content: "I'm happy"
});

newUser.save(function(err,user){
 if (err) {
  console.log(err);
 }else{
  console.log(user);
 }
});
```